# Плавное изменение зафиксированного контента при scroll по примеру

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется конкретный пример реализации.
Сайт: https://www.apple.com/airpods-pro/
Блок о котором идет речь: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При прокрутке этого блока, меняется плавно изображение и текст.
Именно этот эффект я хочу повторить.

Опишу более детально что именно нужно:
При скролле, создается ощущение, что блок зафиксирован и меняется только текст и изображение (причем, плавно, в зависимости от скролла, меняется opacity и transform: matrix)

Если я правильно понимаю, у нас следующая структура html:

```
<div class="section-scroll">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Описание блока #1</p>
        <img src="slide1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Описание блока #2</p>
        <img src="slide2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

.section-scroll имеет height: 100vh (высоту всей страницы).
При скролле на этот блок, сначала просто отображается первый блок content
А далее, если мы скроллим вниз, img и описание первого блока затухает (opacity: 0) и постепенно отображается img и описание второго элемента.

- с помощью matrix создается ощущение "появления" текста с под низу (или верху, в зависимости от скролла).

Нужна помощь в реализации js. Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Просто получаете сколько пикселей от верхнего уровня экрана прокручено относительно блока, к которому добавили `position: relative` (в котором `position: sticky`) через `getboundingclientrect()`

Затем каждые новые `Х` пикселей делаете изменения через `JS` (например,

- вешаете класс на элемент, который меняет изображение в смартфоне (`background-image`)
- делает наушники видимыми, `opacity`
- меняет размер наушников, `transform: scale()`
- двигает текст, `transform: translateY()`
- меняет его видимость, `opacity`

Выглядит очень просто. Но требует некоторого времени, так что писать код не буду. Надеюсь чем-то помог.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Я нашел точный пример, как мне нужно 1:1
https://javascript.ru/forum/misc/80303-kak-sdelat-plavnuyu-smenu-kartinok-pri-skrollinge.html

Но есть проблема с блоков fixed. У меня не получается добавить данный блок куда-то в середину, он налазит на первый блок из-за position: fixed.
У меня не получается это поправить. Если вы подскажите - будет адски круто

Comment: Не знаю как тут сделать с `position: fixed` (и зачем он нужен тут). извините. По-моему тут идеальный вариант для использования `position: sticky` + `position: relative`.